# Bypass color ink cartridge

Tags: windows-10, printing

My Lexmark Pro200-S500 seems to have a problem detecting the yellow cartridge. 
I don’t mind, as I only print in black. In fact, I’m ok with permanently make my printer into a black only printer.

The problem is, it won’t let me print anything even if I specify grayscale or black only. It says the printer will not work until the yellow cartridge is replaced. 
Is there a way to completely disable this feature? Whether on the printer itself or from the computer (Windows 10)?

Answer (score 1):

- It appears that this is an old model printer.  It doesn't look like there has been a driver update since about 2012.  So if you have a driver in Win 10, it pretty much has to be the latest one.
- The [user manual](https://publications.lexmark.com/publications/pdfs/2007/pro200/LXEBuser-en.pdf) is close to useless.  The only relevant advice I could find is if you have a printing problem, replace the ink cartridges.  However, it does mention that there are some maintenance options accessible on the printer, so check there on the off chance there is a setting.
- Many inkjet printers and inkjet all-in-ones won't work at all (even the scanner on an all-in-one), if there is a problem with any ink cartridge, and there typically isn't a way to override that.  The manufacturer will claim that it's to ensure you get the best possible output, but the printers are sold at or below cost and they make their money on the ink cartridges.  So everything is designed to use up ink and to incentivize buying ink.

  I couldn't find any indication or discussion of a way to disable color and still print.  But it wouldn't hurt to contact Lexmark customer support and ask them if there's a way that they don't advertise.
- Worst case, buy the cheapest third party cartridge you can find.  They are usually much cheaper than the OEM cartridges.  In this case, you don't even care about color (although that might be nice to have if you get it working cheaply).  You just need something the printer will recognize so it operates.

  Caveat: The wording in the question is that it doesn't "detect" the yellow cartridge.  It should detect the cartridge but could recognize a problem (out of ink, chip says it printed the design number of pages, sees it as an invalid cartridge, etc.).  If it detects the cartridge but has a problem with it, replacing it should get you operational.  But if it doesn't detect the cartridge at all, there may be some other problem (not unusual when a printer gets old).
- If there's a problem other than a bad ink cartridge, it would not be cost effective to service the printer (if it can even still be serviced; the supply chain carries parts for a finite time, and repair shops may be hesitant to work on a really old printer).  To have someone open it up and diagnose the problem, even before parts and labor to fix it, you could buy a cheap replacement printer, or make a healthy down payment on a good printer.

  So if the printer actually is failing to detect the cartridge, it would probably still be worth the price of a cheap off-brand cartridge just to see if the printer still works.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. Indeed it does not “detect” the cartridge, we already replaced it with a new one but it keeps saying it is an empty cartridge. And as you said fixing the hardware will probably be almost the same price as a new printer. So I was hoping for a software fix.